# Managed Metadata Navigation - Browser Back Button Problem

Tags: 2010, navigation, managed-metadata, internet-explorer, managed-navigation

In our intranet site, we have links in various places that navigate the user to document libraries that are pre-filtered by managed metadata values.

The URLs look like this (with metadata filter applied):

```
/hr/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=Primary%5Fx0020%5FCategory&FilterValue1=17&FilterLookupId1=1&FilterOp1=In&TreeField=Primary%5Fx0020%5FCategory&TreeValue=8a97c4a3%2D4ad4%2D494d%2Dbee4%2Db77c0c81dd7d&OverrideScope=RecursiveAll&ProcessQStringToCAML=1&RootFolder=%2Fhr%2FShared%20Documents#ServerFilter=FilterField1=Primary%5Fx0020%5FCategory-FilterValue1=17-FilterLookupId1=1-FilterOp1=In-TreeField=Primary%5Fx0020%5FCategory-TreeValue=8a97c4a3%2D4ad4%2D494d%2Dbee4%2Db77c0c81dd7d-OverrideScope=RecursiveAll-ProcessQStringToCAML=1
```

When you visit any such page, the filters work great, but the navigation history in the browser has multiple entries, so the back button must be clicked 3 times to get back to the referring URL.  (I have heard that it might be related to AJAX requests.) For example, see the following image, where *Human Resources* is the source URL:

[image: Source Url: Human Resources]

Is there any way to fix this behavior?

Comment: We have decided to open new tabs/windows for the links so there is no back needed. This doesn't answer your question at all, but we feel your pain.